# find common value of one matrix in another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have one matrix *MyMatrix* 2549x13double

Few example lines from *MyMatrix*:

```
-7.80   -4.41   -0.08   2.51    6.31    6.95    4.97    2.91    0.66    -0.92   0.31    1.24    -0.07
4.58    5.87    6.18    6.23    5.20    4.86    5.02    5.33    3.69    1.36    -0.54   0.28    -1.20
-6.22   -3.77   1.18    2.85    -3.55   0.52    3.24    -7.77   -8.43   -9.81   -6.05   -5.88   -7.77
-2.21   -3.21   -4.44   -3.58   -0.89   3.40    6.56    7.20    4.30    -0.77   -5.09   -3.18   0.43
```

I have identified the maximum value for each row of matrix *MyMatrix* as following:

```
 [M Ind] = max(MyMatrix, [], 2);
```

Example lines I obtain in *M*:

```
6.95
6.23
3.24
7.20
```

Now, I would like to select in MyMatrix the 2 values before and after the maximum value as found in *M*, as I will need to calculate the average of these 5 values.
So, in the example, I would like to select:

```
2.51    6.31    6.95    4.97    2.91
5.87    6.18    6.23    5.20    4.86
-3.55   0.52    3.24    -7.77   -8.43
3.40    6.56    7.20    4.30    -0.77
```

and to create a new column in *MyMatrix* with the mean of these 5 values.

I would appreciate any help.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Get the column indices required per row:

```
colInd = bsxfun(@plus,Ind, -2:2)
```

Now it will actually be easier to work with your matrix transposed (`MyMatrixT = MyMatrix.'`) since we will be working with linear indexes so let's rather work with

```
rowIndT = colInd.';
```

Now we want to convert this `Rind` to linear indexes. This is just a case of adding the total number of rows (number of columns in the original) to the column number

```
linIndT = bsxfun(@plus,rowIndT,0:size(MyMatrixT,1):size(MyMatrixT,1)*(size(MyMatrixT,2)-1))
```

And finally we extract the values and transpose back

```
resultT = MyMatrixT(linIndT);
result = resultT.'

result =

    2.5100    6.3100    6.9500    4.9700    2.9100
    5.8700    6.1800    6.2300    5.2000    4.8600
   -3.5500    0.5200    3.2400   -7.7700   -8.4300
    3.4000    6.5600    7.2000    4.3000   -0.7700
```

The new column is just the mean of result:

```
mean(result,2)
```

and to append it to your matrix

```
MyMatrix = [MyMatrix, mean(result,2)]
```

Now there is still one problem, what happens if a maximum is near the edge (i.e. if a maximum is in column 2, then two values before the maximum is not defined). How to deal with this will require you to first define the behavior you desire in such situations. But let's assume you want `NaN`, then I would do this:

```
colInd = bsxfun(@plus,Ind, -2:2);
rowIndT = colInd.';

%  Bound rowIndT to be between 1 and size(MyMatrixT,1)
rowIndT(rowIndT < 1) = 1;
rowIndT(rowIndT > size(MyMatrixT,1)) = size(MyMatrixT,1);

linIndT = bsxfun(@plus,rowIndT,0:size(MyMatrixT,1):size(MyMatrixT,1)*(size(MyMatrixT,2)-1)); % You can use sub2ind instead for this step
result = MyMatrixT(linIndT).';

% Now go back and put NaNs where they are needed
nanColInd = colInd < 1 | colInd > size(MyMatrix,2);
result(nanColInd) = NaN;
% Now use nanmean to ignore any NaNs when finding the mean
MyMatrix = [MyMatrix, nanmean(result,2)]
```

One last thing, you might find it more intuitive to use `sub2ind` to find the linear indexes. In that case

```
linIndT = bsxfun(@plus,rowIndT,0:size(MyMatrixT,1):size(MyMatrixT,1)*(size(MyMatrixT,2)-1))
```

becomes

```
linIndT = sub2ind(size(MyMatrixT), rowIndT, repmat(1:size(MyMatrixT,2),size(rowIndT,1),1))
```

Comment: +1 Excellent.  All bases appear to be covered with great explanations, well done.  I wish SO would allow more up votes for quality.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanations @Dan ! Much appreciated.

Comment: @Dan How can I change the last part of the code if I want NaN only when the maximum is the first or last column of `MyMatrix`? Instead when the maximum is in the second column, I would like to calculate the mean considering one column preceding the maximum, the maximum value, and two columns following the maximum. While, when the maximum is in the second last column, I would like to consider the two columns preceding the maximum, the maximum value, and only one column following the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

This will take avg of 2 elements before and after the maximum and store it in the end column

```
endRow = size(MyMatrix,2) + 1
for i = 1:size(MyMatrix,1)

        MyMatrix(i,endRow) =  mean(MyMatrix(i,max(Ind(i)-2,0):min(Ind(i)+2,end)));


end
```

Update: Sorry I have updated which stores in the last column

Comment: Instead of making the mean `0`, you could use `min` and `max` like this to just ignore elements that are "off the edges" `mean(MyMatrix(i,max(Ind(i)-2,1):min(Ind(i)+2,end)))`

Comment: well with that update you no longer need the `if` statement ;) also you could replace your `endRow` with `end+1`. I think using a loop in this situation is a pretty good solution btw, definitely easier to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the correction:) I tried end +1 it creates a new column for every iteration and stores the means in a new column and nnumber of column would increase with each iteration(actually that was my first approach) , Thanks for appreciation