# mean based on maximum value of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, max, mean

This post follows up another post: [find common value of one matrix in another matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704995/find-common-value-of-one-matrix-in-another-matrix)

As  I explained there, I have one matrix MyMatrix 2549x13double

Few example lines from MyMatrix:

```
-7.80   -4.41   -0.08   2.51    6.31    6.95    4.97    2.91    0.66    -0.92   0.31    1.24    -0.07
 4.58    5.87    6.18    6.23    5.20    4.86    5.02    5.33    3.69    1.36    -0.54   0.28    -1.20
-6.22   -3.77   1.18    2.85    -3.55   0.52    3.24    -7.77   -8.43   -9.81   -6.05   -5.88   -7.77
-2.21   -3.21   -4.44   -3.58   -0.89   3.40    6.56    7.20    4.30    -0.77   -5.09   -3.18   0.43
```

I have identified the maximum value for each row of matrix MyMatrix as following:

[M Ind] = max(MyMatrix, [], 2);
Example lines I obtain in M:

```
6.95
6.23
3.24
7.20
```

Now, I would like to select in MyMatrix the 2 values before and after the maximum value as found in M, as I will need to calculate the average of these 5 values. So, in the example, I would like to select:

```
2.51    6.31    6.95    4.97    2.91
5.87    6.18    6.23    5.20    4.86
-3.55   0.52    3.24    -7.77   -8.43
3.40    6.56    7.20    4.30    -0.77
```

and to create a new column in MyMatrix with the mean of these 5 values.

Following the code by @Dan, taken from the previous post:

```
colInd = bsxfun(@plus,PeakInd, -2:2);
MyMatrixT = MyMatrix.';
rowIndT = colInd.';
linIndT = bsxfun(@plus,rowIndT,0:size(MyMatrixT,1):size(MyMatrixT,1)*(size(MyMatrixT,2)-1));
resultT = MyMatrixT(linIndT);
result = resultT.';
mean(result,2)
MyMatrix = [MyMatrix, mean(result,2)];
```

Here is the new part of the post, regarding the issue when the maximum value is near the edges.
When the maximum is the first or last column of MyMatrix, I would like to have NaN.

Instead, when the maximum is in the second column, I would like to calculate the mean considering one column preceding the maximum, the maximum value, and two columns following the maximum.

While, when the maximum is in the second last column, I would like to consider the two columns preceding the maximum, the maximum value, and only one column following the maximum.

I would be extremely grateful if you could help me. Many thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure that's what my second code does, just uses `nanmean`. So if your max was in column 2 then you'll get something like `[NaN, 6,10, 4, 2]` so `nanmean` will give you the mean of `[6,10,4,2]` which uses 1 column preeding and two column following the max...

Comment: Only thing to add about @Dan 's comment is that in order to get `NaN` if your maximum is on the first or last column you just have to change it in the end. (Say the column you're about to add is called `M2` and the number of columns of your original matrix was `N`, you'll need a call to `M2(Ind==1|Ind==N)=NaN;`)

Comment: @BillBokeey no I meant I already answered it completely here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37705364/1011724

Comment: I just pointed out the fact that OP wants a `NaN` in the row he's adding if the maximum is in the first column (resp last.). I believe your code will out a non-NaN value on calls like `nanmean([NaN NaN value value value])`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a 2D array with NaNs plus `nanmean`, you could use `min`/`max` to get the right indexes:

```
pad = 2;
[~, Ind] = max(MyMatrix, [], 2);
minCol = max(1, Ind-pad);
maxCol = min(size(MyMatrix, 2), Ind+pad);
result = arrayfun(@(row, min_, max_) mean(MyMatrix(row, min_:max_)),...
                  (1:size(MyMatrix, 1)).', minCol, maxCol);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can also use [`padarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/padarray.html), e.g.

```
B = padarray(magic(5),[0 2],NaN);

B =

   NaN   NaN    17    24     1     8    15   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN    23     5     7    14    16   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN     4     6    13    20    22   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN    10    12    19    21     3   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN    11    18    25     2     9   NaN   NaN
```

(...if you don't have `padarray`, just manually add 2 NaN columns on either side) then using some [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) + [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) we get the desired result:

```
pad_sz = 2;
B = padarray(magic(5),[0 pad_sz],NaN);
[~,I] = nanmax(B,[],2); % by using nanmax we "explicitly" say we ignore NaNs.
colInd = bsxfun(@plus,-pad_sz:pad_sz,I);
linearInd = sub2ind(size(B), repmat((1:5).',[1,size(colInd,2)]), colInd);
picks = B(linearInd);
res = nanmean(picks,2);
% or combine the last 3 lines into:
% res = nanmean(B(sub2ind(size(B), repmat((1:5).',[1,size(colInd,2)]), colInd)),2);
res = res + 0./~(I == pad_sz+1 | I == size(B,2)-pad_sz); %add NaN where needed.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I want NaN as mean, only when the maximum is on the first or last column (It's ok if the maximum is in the second or second last columns).